# session is not clearing correctly please help me on this

Tags: php, javascript, session

i made a little application to make invoices. but there is a small problem.
it work like this
1) type item code or name in text box and click a button to add that item into two dimensional session variable
2) then i echo that session array item in to a table in screen.

now what the problem is, if i wanted to cancel the whole bill.  i tried to unset the session array by clicking a button. 
but it is not working as i hope.i can clear the session only for one time. what i mean is 
after adding some items i cleared the session and tried to add same item again so without a problem i could do it. but again i tried to clear the session and add the same items. now it says "you are trying to add the same item twice" ( i made this error to popup when trying to add the same item without cancelling the bill)

here is my code

```
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function clearsessin() {
     var actualkey = "y";
     location.href="biling.php?cmd="+actualkey;
    }
</script>
<?php if(isset($_GET['cmd'])){
session_unset();
session_destroy();
$_SESSION["bill_array"] = array();
header('location:biling.php') ;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use `unset($_SESSION["your_var"]);` and try to do that before assignment of your session array

Comment: thanks this is now working on Internet Explorer. but not in fire fox and chrome. i mainly focus google chrome but this is not working on it can i correct it any how?

Comment: hm, i think it is not depend upon browser, that function working correct in all browsers in my code, may be thee issue not in this. I think the problem is in your javascript, try to debug your code in browsers which you need, write console.log() or alert(), line by line and in that way you will find the problem line in your code and replace it.

Comment: i restart the computer to make sure there is no cache. but still this works on IE but not in chrome.